# Is there anyway to get the amount of asset which you sent?

Tags: java-sdk

as an ashore is there anyway to get the amount of the asset which you sent to the other wallets?
like the the addition operation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizon endpoint can show you [all operations for an account](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=operations&endpoint=for_account&network=test). e.g. https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDZC37RX2NTKXOG4TPSCZVI5PUSSNP2HJJJOIU7RWNAN5ZL2UHAF2HK3/operations?limit=200

In the Java SDK, this endpoint is represented by [OperationsRequestBuilder.forAccount](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/requests/OperationsRequestBuilder.java#L51-L60).

You can filter the results for create account & payment operations to see how much has directly been sent for the assets you care about.

If you are trying to find matched trades, then this can be inspected by filtering on the [effects for an account](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?resource=effects&endpoint=for_account&network=test) ([example](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDZC37RX2NTKXOG4TPSCZVI5PUSSNP2HJJJOIU7RWNAN5ZL2UHAF2HK3/effects?limit=200), [java](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/requests/EffectsRequestBuilder.java#L33-L42)). (Payments will also appear in the effects list as debits).